# Uploading of files and saving

Tags: php, mysql

back again

So I have moved the code around a bit and now only get the unsuccessfull message. Please tell me where and what I am doing wrong.

My form on the editemployee.php page

```
<h1>Warnings</h1>
<div class="article" style="width:535px">
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="includes/add.php" method="POST"> 
 <table>
  <tr>
  <td>Warning letter:</td>
  <td> <input type="file" name="warning1"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>Warning letter:</td>
  <td><input type="file" name="warning2"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>Warning letter Final:</td>
  <td><input type="file" name="warning3"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Add"> </td>
  </tr>
  </table>

 </form>

 </div>
```

An now I have move the processing code as suggested to its own file called add.php

```
<?php 
  //This is the directory where images will be saved 
$target = "files/empdocs"; 
$target1 = $target . basename( $_FILES['warning1']['name']); 
$target2 = $target . basename( $_FILES['warning2']['name']);
$target3 = $target . basename( $_FILES['warning3']['name']);

 //This gets all the other information from the form 

 $warning1=($_FILES['warning1']['name']); 
 $warning2=($_FILES['warning2']['name']);
 $warning3=($_FILES['warning3']['name']); 

 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
 mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

  //Writes the information to the database 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO ref_employees VALUES ('$warning1', '$warning2', '$warning3')") ;
  //Writes the file to the server 
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['warning1']['tmp_name'], $target1)
&& move_uploaded_file($_FILES['warning2']['tmp_name'], $target2)
&& move_uploaded_file($_FILES['warning3']['tmp_name'], $target3)) {

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: Which one of your messages are being printed as a result of this code being executed?  or is there an error message?

Comment: There is no message printed, simply routes through to the same page as if just loaded.... Sorry should have mentioned that it is only the warning form giving the issue...

Comment: Try to not mixing frontend code with backend one and the last one: code indentation FTW!.

Comment: You shouldn't use mysql_* functions anymore, they are deprecated  -> http://php.net/manual/de/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: @MauriceBotha For one thing, you're using and asking for `GET` methods where your form is `POST` method.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ref_employees VALUES ('$warning1', '$warning2', '$warningfinal') WHERE 'idnumber' = $idnumber") ;
```

`WHERE` should not be in `INSERT` statement!

Comment: That's a good point, and there shouldn't be apostrophes around the column name `'idnumber'`

Answer (score 0):

There is no something like this:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['warning1']['tmp_name'], $target))
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['warning2']['tmp_name'], $target))
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['warning3']['tmp_name'], $target))  {
```

You have to

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['warning1']['tmp_name'], $target1)
&& move_uploaded_file($_FILES['warning2']['tmp_name'], $target2)
&& move_uploaded_file($_FILES['warning3']['tmp_name'], $target3)) {
```

And target variable, not like this:

```
$target = "files/empdocs"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['warning1']['name']); 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['warning2']['name']);
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['warning3']['name']);
```

But:

```
$target = "files/empdocs"; 
$target1 = $target . basename( $_FILES['warning1']['name']); 
$target2 = $target . basename( $_FILES['warning2']['name']);
$target2 = $target . basename( $_FILES['warning3']['name']);
```

Comment: Thank you, with your solution I am at least now getting my error message

Comment: What help you need? I have show you where you have some error. What error you getting now?

Answer (score 0):

If you want use JQuery and PHP to upload multifiles with a nice UI you can check this link and try JQuery-File-Upload library. It is very nice libs.

I think it will helps you

the link is 
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload